# Full Calendar 5 - change month update url

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I'm using Full Calendar https://fullcalendar.io/ and have everything working as I want except for one thing. When navigating to the next/previous month I'd like the url bar to update so that it's possible to share a direct link to that month.

Currently at domain.com/events clicking next/prev moves the month but the url is not updated.

Is this possible?

In case it's relevant this is the javascript I'm using

```
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    headerToolbar: {
      start: '',
      center: 'prev title next',
      end: ''
    },
    locale: '{{ craft.app.language }}',
    showNonCurrentDates: true,
    fixedWeekCount: false,

    // event display block removes dot
    eventDisplay:'block',
    eventClassNames: 'has-event',
    eventColor: '#de242b',
    eventBorderColor: '#fff',
    eventTextColor: '#fff',
    eventBackgroundColor: '#de242b',

    events: [
      // add in event stuff here
      {% for event in craft.entries.section('events').all() %}


        {% set eventEnd %}
          {% if event.eventEndDate|length %}
            {{ event.eventEndDate|date('Y-m-d')|json_encode|raw }} + 'T23:59:00'
          {% else %}
            {{ event.eventStartDate|date('Y-m-d')|json_encode|raw }} + 'T23:59:00'
          {% endif %}
        {% endset %}

        {
          title: {{ event.title|json_encode|raw }},
          start: {{ event.eventStartDate|date('Y-m-d')|json_encode|raw }},
          end: {{ eventEnd }},
          url: {{ event.url|json_encode|raw }},
          textColor: 'white',
          backgroundColor:'#de242b',
        },
      {% endfor %}
    ]
  });

  calendar.render();
});
```

Comment: If you handle the click events on those buttons you could add some JavaScript to update the URL, yes. But beware, those buttons are not the only way to change the date range. And if the user presses the back button you'd need code to handle that too, and set the appropriate date in the calendar

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this as I am wanting to do the same?